# Listing questions and viewing questions shows different users

Tags: support

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294661/pandas-save-dataframe-to-open-workbook) when viewed, is attributed to user '[orange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1230724/orange)',
[image: Question view]
but when seen from the [list of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/pandas), it is attributed to the user '[bakkal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238639/bakkal)'
[image: List view]

Comment: Above of `bakkal` you can see `modified` ;).

Comment: I guess bakkal has a deleted answer to that question.

Comment: @shA.t, so this is desired behaviour? Very confusing and unintuitive.

Comment: When you have 10,000 reputation you will be able to see the deleted answer (I'm assuming). Until then, once you know what is happening, you get to live with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will note that above the user name in the listing there is the word "modified". Not "asked".

This is because this user *answered* the question (though that answer is now deleted).

Comment: So is this a caching issue or is it supposed to be this way? Seems very unintuitive...

Comment: It is by design

Comment: @firelynx - the very last action on the question was an answer (which was since deleted). The list reflects that action.